# Why are a and d not getting pressed the same amount?

Tags: autohotkey

I need a macro to press "a" then "d" shortly after and i need them to be pressed the same amount but it isn't working, how can i fix this?

```
Loop {
  Send {s down}
  Click, right
  Sleep, 1
  Send {d up}
  Send {a down}
  Click, R

  Send {s down}
  Click, right
  Sleep, 1
  Send {a up}
  Send {d down}
  Click, R
}
```

Comment: You never sent `{s up}`, btw.

Comment: @D.Pardal is there a way that i can balance the button presses though?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what the hole script should do?

If you just want to press "a" and afterwards "d", don't use the "up" and "down" parameters.

```
1::
Loop{
send {a}
send {d}
}
```

If you need the buttons to be pressed an precise amount of time, work with some sleeps.

```
1::
Loop{
send {a down}
sleep x
send {a up}
send {d down}
sleep x
send {d up}
}
```